# Fundamental Solution of a Nonlinear ODE (using Riccati Transformation & Wronskian)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the differential equation:
\begin{equation*}
y^{\prime}(t) = y(t)^{2} + 2\sin(t)\cos(t) - \sin^{4}(t)
\end{equation*}
and one solution $y_{1}(t) = \sin^{2}(t)$.

I wish to find a second solution, and I am told this second solution should also be periodic.

To find the second solution $y_{2}$, I use the following steps:

1.) Convert the nonlinear differential equation to a second order system of differential equations using the Riccati transformation: $y = -z^{\prime}/z$.

This gives me the form: $z^{\prime}(t) = A(t)z$ with 
\begin{equation*}
A(t) = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
-2\sin(t)\cos(t)-\sin^{4}(t) & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{equation*}
and solving $-y_{1}(t) = -\sin^{2}(t) = z^{\prime}/z$,
\begin{alignat*}{2}
z(t) = ce^{-\int_{0}^{t}\sin^{2}(s)ds}, \\
z^{\prime}(t) = -c\sin^{2}(t)e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\sin^{2}(s)ds}
\end{alignat*}
(I dispense with the common constant $c$ since I'm using a general solution matrix in the next step).

2.) Form the Wronskian matrix with known $z(t)$ and unknown $\phi(t)$, and use Abel's formula to solve for $\phi(t)$, i.e.

\begin{alignat*}{2}
W(t) &= \left|
\begin{matrix}
z(t) & \phi(t) \\
z^{\prime}(t) & \phi^{\prime}(t)
\end{matrix}
\right| \\
&= z(t)\phi^{\prime}(t) - z^{\prime}(t)\phi(t) \\
&= W_{0}e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\text{tr}(A(s))ds} \\
&= W_{0}e^{-\int_{0}^{t}0ds} \\
&= W_{0}
\end{alignat*}

3.) Solving the resulting differential equation for $\phi$.  Thus,
\begin{alignat*}{2}
z(t)\phi^{\prime}(t) - z^{\prime}(t)\phi(t) &= W_{0} &&\Rightarrow \\
z(t)\phi^{\prime}(t) + \sin^{2}(t)z(t)\phi(t) &= W_{0} &&\Rightarrow \\
\phi^{\prime}(t) + \sin^{2}(t)\phi(t) &= W_{0}z^{-1}(t) &&\Rightarrow
\end{alignat*}
Let $\mu(t) = z^{-1}(t)$, and multiply both sides by $\mu$
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\mu(t)\phi^{\prime}(t) + \sin^{2}(t)\mu(t)\phi(t) &= W_{0}\mu^{2}(t) &&\Rightarrow \\
\mu(t)\phi^{\prime}(t) + \mu^{\prime}(t)\phi(t) &= W_{0}\mu^{2}(t)&&\Rightarrow \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\mu(t)\phi(t)\right) &= W_{0}\mu^{2} \\
\mu(t)\phi(t) &= W_{0}\int_{0}^{t}\mu^{2}(s)ds &&\Rightarrow \\
\phi(t) &= W_{0}z(t)\int_{0}^{t}\mu^{2}(s)ds &&\Rightarrow \\
\phi^{\prime}(t) &= W_{0}z^{\prime}(t)\int_{0}^{t}\mu^{2}(s)ds
+W_{0}z(t)\mu^{2}(t)
\end{alignat*}

4.) Convert back using the same Riccati transformation:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
y_{2}(t) &= -\frac{\phi^{\prime}(t)}{\phi(t)} \\
&= -y_{1}(t) - \frac{\mu^{2}(t)}{\int_{0}^{t}\mu^{2}(s)ds}.  
\end{alignat*}

However, this result does not look like it is going to solve the original nonlinear differential equation nor does it seem periodic.  I would like to determine if I have made a calculation error or if there is a flaw in my understanding of this material or a combination of both.

Comment: Using the transformation at the bottom of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html, I think the more general solution you are seeking should be the solution of $v'(t) = - 2 \sin^2(t) v(t) - 1$, and I agree that it doesn't appear to be periodic.